# CandleStick chart prepare data (open,close,high ,low)

Tags: r, candlestick-chart

```
InvoiceDate<-c("2018-01-01 08:26:00","2018-01-01 08:26:00","2018-01-01 08:26:00","2018-01-01 08:26:00","2018-01-02 08:26:00","2018-01-02 08:26:00","2018-01-02 08:26:00","2018-01-02 08:26:00","2018-01-03 08:26:00","2018-01-04 08:26:00","2018-01-04 08:26:00","2018-01-04 08:26:00")
UnitPrice<-c(2.27,2.28,2.29,2.30,2.31,2.32,3.22,5.26,2,26,3.23,2.50)
myData<-data.frame(InvoiceDate,UnitPrice)
```

I want create a candleStick graph. But my question is how to compute  open,close,high ,low values. Is there any library in R   ? Thank you.

And my loop:

```
    df<-data.frame(

  open=double(),
  close=double(),
  min=double(),
  max=double(),
  date=as.Date(character())

)



firstDate<-as.Date(myData$InvoiceDate[1])
firstOpen<-myData$UnitPrice[1]
min<-myData$UnitPrice[1]
max<-myData$UnitPrice[1]


for(row in 1:nrow(myData))
{

  actualDate<-as.Date(myData$InvoiceDate[row])
  actualPrice<-myData$UnitPrice[row]

  if(actualDate==firstDate)
  {

    if(min>actualPrice)
    {
      min<-actualPrice
    }


    if(max<actualPrice)
    {
      max<-actualPrice
    }

  }


  if(actualDate!=firstDate)
  {
    open=firstOpen
    close=myData$UnitPrice[row-1]
    date=as.Date(myData$InvoiceDate[row-1])

    values<-data.frame(open,close,minPrice,maxPrice,date)
    df<-rbind(df,values)

    firstDate<-actualDate
    firstOpen<-myData$UnitPrice[row]
    min<-myData$UnitPrice[row]
    max<-myData$UnitPrice[row]

  }


}
```

So  open value mean that it is first value in each date 
and close value is last value in each date.
Min and max is minimum and maximum value in each date

It is working but miss row with last date in example it is "2018-01-04 08:26:00"

Comment: What did you tried till now ?

Comment: I tried to write my own  for loop but it is not funcional.

Comment: Can you add a sample of your data (with the result of dput), and paste your code, so someone can help you ?

Comment: I added this...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So maybe you can use dplyr : 
(here I assume that your data are sorted in chronologic order, you may need to sort or arrange somewhere) :

```
library(dplyr)
myData %>% group_by(trunc(as.Date(InvoiceDate), "day")) %>% summarize(open_val = first(UnitPrice), close_val = last(UnitPrice), max_val = max(UnitPrice), min_val = min(UnitPrice))
```